# Java/MongoDB query by date

Tags: java, datetime, mongodb

I stored a value as a java.util.Date() in my collection, but when I query to get values between two specific dates, I end up getting values outside of the range. Here's my code:

to insert

```
BasicDBObject object = new BasicDBObject();
...
object.put("dateAdded", new java.util.Date());
collection.insert(object);
```

to query

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("dateAdded", new BasicDBObject("$gte", fromDate));
query.put("dateAdded", new BasicDBObject("$lte", toDate));
collection.find(query).sort(new BasicDBObject("dateAdded", -1));
```

when I query between `Wed Jul 27 16:54:49 EST 2011` and `Wed Jul 27 16:54:49 EST 2011` (basically fromDate = toDate), I get objects with dates like `Tue Jul 26 09:43:37 EST 2011` which should definitely not be possible. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

What you're doing is querying only with `{$lte: toDate}` losing `$gte` operator in the key overwrite. What you want is:

```
query.put("dateAdded", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", fromDate).add("$lte", toDate).get());
```

Comment: Excellent tip! So basically every time I want to query on the same field with different criteria I have to use the builder right? good to know! Where did you find this? is there any documentation I'm not aware of? (since the mongodb official java tutorial is quite poor!)

Comment: @Guillaume Not exactly. You can also create and populate `BasicDBObject`, the builder is just helper that allows to do it inside a single satement. The problem is that `DBObject` (like all `Map`s in Java) can contain only unique keys. And you lose the previous value when putting new one with the same key. Also official tutorial has example on how to use multiple operators on the same field: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial#JavaTutorial-GettingASetofDocumentsWithaQuery

Comment: Surprisingly hard finding the answer to that question.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using MongoTemplate of Spring-Data Mongodb, you can do the same in following way:-

```
public List<Link> getLinksBetweenDate(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
            Query query = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("updatedOn").gt(startDate).lte(endDate));
            return mongoTemplate.find(query, Link.class);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Using mongo client 3.0

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
Bson filter = new Document("$gte", format.parse("2015-05-01T00:00:00Z")).append("$lt", format.parse("2015-05-02T00:00:00Z"));
long count = db.getCollection("colection").count(new Document("field",filter) );
```

Comment: What does long count return? What is contained within this variable? How do you extract database entries from this variable?

Comment: You should never enclose `Z` within single quotes. Check the correct way at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65710515/10819573

Answer (score 4):

Search Date with specific format following steps are that this also work in mongo 3.0

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd");
```

First convert your date in your specific format, you can use any format and parse your date with above format and then pass in query.

```
String date ="2014.01.02"; 
String data1 ="2014.01.10";
Date startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);  
Date endDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date1);
```

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("fieldName",
   new BasicDBObject("$gte",startDate).append("$lt",endDate ));
```

So base on your requirement you can search date by giving argument in `BasicDBobject`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
    import org.bson.conversions.Bson;
    import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Bson filter = Filters.and(gte("date_field", format.parse("2018-10-01")),
                            lt("date_field", format.parse("2019-10-01")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I approach the query like this

```
new Document("datetime",Document.parse(
    "{$gte: ISODate('" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(fromDate) + "'), 
     $lte: ISODate('" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(endDate) + "')}"
))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact answers to do one more thing when you applying the date range use the UTC time for the same.

On your local machine, you can use the below code to find the UTC time from your machine or server:

```
java.util.TimeZone.setDefault(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```