# Date query with ISODate in mongodb doesn't seem to work

Tags: json, mongodb, bson, isodate

I don't seem to be able to get even the most basic date query to work in MongoDB.  With a document that looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "foobar/201310",
    "ap" : "foobar",
    "dt" : ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "tl" : 375439
}
```

And a query that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "dt" : { 
        "$gte" : { 
            "$date" : "2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }
}
```

I get **0 results** from executing:

```
db.mycollection.find({
  "dt" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
})
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

For reference, this query is being produced by [Spring's MongoTemplate](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/) so I don't have direct control over the query that is ultimately sent to MongoDB.

(P.S.)

```
> db.version()
2.4.7
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 396, accepted):

Although `$date` is a part of [MongoDB Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) and that's what you get as default with `mongoexport`, I don't think you can really use it as a part of the query.

If try exact search with `$date` like below:

```js
db.foo.find({dt: {"$date": "2012-01-01T15:00:00.000Z"}})
```

you'll get the error:

```
error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $date", "code" : 10068 }
```

Try this:

```js
db.mycollection.find({
    "dt" : {"$gte": new Date("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")}
})
```

or (following comments by [@user3805045](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3805045/user3805045)):

```js
db.mycollection.find({
    "dt" : {"$gte": ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")}
})
```

`ISODate` may be also required to compare dates without time (noted by [@MattMolnar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119909/matt-molnar)).

According to [Data Types in the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/) both should be equivalent:

> The mongo shell provides various methods to return the date, either as a string or as a Date object:
>
> - Date() method which returns the current date as a string.
> - new Date() constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper.
> - ISODate() constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper.

and using `ISODate` [should still return a Date object](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Date/#return-date-as-date-object).

`{"$date": "ISO-8601 string"}` can be used when strict JSON representation is required. One possible example is Hadoop connector.

Comment: Yeah.  I think I was thrown off by what is returned when you print out the ```Query``` object in Spring.  The serialized form of the query is not necessarily a valid query that you can just copy/paste into a mongo shell, which in itself is kind of frustrating.  The culprit is here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.8.0/com/mongodb/util/JSONSerializers.java#208

Comment: When comparing a partial (no time) date, I had to switch from `new Date('2016-03-09')` to `ISODate('2016-03-09')`. The former would return dates in the past for a `$gte` query.

Comment: @MattMolnar Noted, and updated the answer with an attribution. Thanks.

Answer (score 115):

From the [MongoDB cookbook](https://web.archive.org/web/20140802203425/http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/) page comments:

```
"dt" : 
{
    "$gte" : ISODate("2014-07-02T00:00:00Z"), 
    "$lt" : ISODate("2014-07-03T00:00:00Z") 
}
```

This worked for me. In full context, the following command gets every record where the `dt` date field has a date on 2013-10-01 (YYYY-MM-DD) Zulu:

```
db.mycollection.find({ "dt" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2013-10-02T00:00:00Z") }})
```

Comment: I got an "ISODate undefined" error. I couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: @BatuhanAkkaya In python with pymongo, `datetime.datetime` is equivalent to `ISODate`.

Comment: @jtbr Not quite.  The equivalent of `ISODate("2014-07-02T00:00:00Z")` is `datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-07-02T00:00:00Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").isoformat()`.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
{ "dt" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2013-10-01") } }
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using robomongo as the mongodb client gui and the below worked for me

```
db.collectionName.find({"columnWithDateTime" : {
$lt:new ISODate("2016-02-28T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

On the app side I am using nodejs based driver mongodb(v1.4.3),the application uses datepicker in the ui which gives date like YYYY-mm-dd, this is then appended with default time like 00:00:00 and then given to the `new Date()` constructor and then supplied to the mongodb criteria object,I think the driver converts the date to ISO date and the query then works and gives desired output, however the same `new Date()` constructor does not work or show same output on robo mongo,for the same criteria,which is weird,since I used robomongo to cross check my criteria objects.

Whereas the default cli mongoshell works well with both `ISODate` and `new Date()`

Comment: Thank you for the tip, Robomongo is way better than Mongo Compass

Answer (score 5):

In json strict mode, you'll have to keep the order:

```
{
    "dt": {
        "$gte": {
            "$date": "2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }
}
```

Only thing which worked to define my search queries on mlab.com.

Comment: Error running query. Reason: (invalid_operator) Invalid operator: $date

Answer (score 3):

*this is my document*

```
"_id" : ObjectId("590173023c488e9a48e903d6"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-04-27T04:26:42.709Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-04-27T04:26:42.709Z"),
    "flightId" : "590170f97cb84116075e2680",

 "_id" : ObjectId("590173023c488e9a48e903d6"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-04-28T03:26:42.609Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-04-28T03:26:42.609Z"),
        "flightId" : "590170f97cb84116075e2680",
```

now i want to find every 27th date document.so i used this....

```
 > db.users.find({createdAt:{"$gte":ISODate("2017-04-27T00:00:00Z"),"$lt":ISODate("2017-04-28T00:00:00Z") }}).count()

result:1
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it with `new Date()`:

```
{ "dt" : { "$lt" : new Date("2012-01-01T15:00:00.000Z") } }
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but still first google hit, so i post it here so i find it again more easily...

Using  Mongo 4.2 and an aggregate():

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
     { $match: { "end_time": { "$gt": ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")  } } },
     { $project: {
          "end_day": { $dateFromParts: { 'year' : {$year:"$end_time"}, 'month' : {$month:"$end_time"}, 'day': {$dayOfMonth:"$end_time"}, 'hour' : 0  } }
     }}, 
     {$group:{
        _id:   "$end_day",
        "count":{$sum:1},
    }}
   ]
)
```

This one give you the groupby variable as a date, sometimes better to hande as the components itself.

Answer (score 2):

In the MongoDB shell:

```
db.getCollection('sensorevents').find({from:{$gt: new ISODate('2015-08-30 16:50:24.481Z')}})
```

In my nodeJS code ( using Mongoose )

```
    SensorEvent.Model.find( {
        from: { $gt: new Date( SensorEventListener.lastSeenSensorFrom ) }
    } )
```

I am querying my sensor events collection to return values where the 'from' field is greater than the given date

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please just post the answer to the question, and not extra stuff like "This is my first post". Think of Stack Overflow as Wikipedia, not a message board.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me while searching for value less than or equal than now:

```
db.collectionName.find({ "dt": { "$lte" : new Date() + "" } });
```

Comment: works in compass, but not in Atlas.

Answer (score 0):

Although I tested this against AWS DocumentDB (which is supposed to be Mongo 4 compatible), this worked fine for me without any use of `Date`or `ISODate`:

```
db.collection_name.find({"an_iso_date_field": {$lte: "2021-02-04T03:42:00Z"}})
```