# Query Date on Mongo not working

Tags: java, mongodb

I try to get a log with a date field on MongoDb called "fecha".

After the execution of my code in Java, I get the next query:

```
{ "fecha" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2015-02-03T01:00:00.000Z"} , "$lt" : { "$date" : "2015-11-22T01:00:00.000Z"}}}
```

But I don't get any result. These are some samples of the data:

```
{ "fecha" : ISODate("2015-11-17T07:47:39.709Z") }
{ "fecha" : ISODate("2015-11-17T07:47:42.760Z") }
{ "fecha" : ISODate("2015-11-17T07:47:45.069Z") }
{ "fecha" : ISODate("2015-11-17T07:47:46.874Z") }
{ "fecha" : ISODate("2015-11-17T07:47:47.831Z") }
{ "fecha" : ISODate("2015-11-17T07:47:49.838Z") }
{ "fecha" : ISODate("2015-11-17T07:47:50.867Z") }
{ "fecha" : ISODate("2015-11-17T07:47:53.534Z") }
{ "fecha" : ISODate("2015-11-17T07:47:55.348Z") }
{ "fecha" : ISODate("2015-11-17T07:47:59.271Z") }
{ "fecha" : ISODate("2015-11-17T07:48:06.782Z") }
```

My Java code is the next:

```
Date dateI = Date.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(0));
Date dateF = Date.from(Instant.now());

if(!fechaInicial.isEmpty()){
    dateI = Date.from(LocalDateTime.parse(fechaInicial).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
}    

if(!fechaFinal.isEmpty()){
    dateF = Date.from(LocalDateTime.parse(fechaFinal).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
}

builder.put("fecha").greaterThan(dateI).lessThan(dateF);

List<DBObject> dbo = bitacoraEjercicios.find(builder.get()).toArray();
return dbo.toString();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are something wrong in your builder, maybe it generates some incorrect query.  `$data` is not supported by mongo query.  Please see this [Date query with ISODate in mongodb doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819870/date-query-with-isodate-in-mongodb-doesnt-seem-to-work)