# Java how to fetch document from mongodb by date

Tags: java, mongodb

Good day,

First i saved a document in mongodb from java and for time i passed.

```
new Date();
```

so it saved a document like this.

```
"time" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad330019a04451b1ab8523d"),
    "created" : ISODate("2018-04-19T20:12:29.512+0000"), 
    "lastModified" : null
}
```

Now i would like to fetch all the documents matching date 2018-04-19 no matter what time it was.

how can i do that please help.

Comment: This post will give you some information on querying on Date https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819870/date-query-with-isodate-in-mongodb-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: Which technologies you are using?

Comment: A "single day" is actually a **range** of possible date values ( based in milliseconds since epoch ) between the "start" of the day you want  inclusive of `0` seconds into the day, and the "start of the next day" exclusive `{ "$gte": startDate, "$lt": endDate }`

Comment: thats great. i was hoping that was supported by mongo java drivers.