# Get all docs by a given date ? (createdAt)

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have this date given by a date picker widget:

```
let targetDate = '2019-01-12';
```

All my documents have a createtAt date generated by timestamps:

```
"createdAt": "2019-01-12T21:49:05.546Z"
```

I want to get all documents that field createdAt matches with my given date.
I tried using $elemMatch:

```
const allDailies = await Daily.find({ createdAt: { $elemMatch: dateTarget } });

const allDailies = await Daily.find({ createdAt: { $elemMatch: { from: dateTarget, to: dateTarget} } });
```

And no one works, how can I do this query? Actually I can't modify my Schema :(

**EDIT:**

```
router.get('/daily/:date', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const targetDate = new RegExp(`^${req.params.date}`);
    const allDailies = await Daily.find({ createdAt: { $regex: targetDate } });
    console.log('Dailies', allDailies);
    return res.json({ allDailies });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.sendStatus(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
});
```

It returns a 500 error

Comment: is the value of `createdAt` an object or an iso date - time string?

Comment: yep is a ISO date

Comment: console.log(error) on the catch block and show the kind of error

Comment: OK, this says Error: Can't use $regex with Date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819870/date-query-with-isodate-in-mongodb-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: Wow more easy than I thought thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `targetDate` to the same type as `createdAt` and use it on query as `tatgetDate`. Not `dateTarget` as you use it now (you typed it wrong).

Comment: I can't because my targetData is given from the frontend by a date picker widget

Comment: is it "targetDate" or "dateTarget"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your target date in to ISODate format. But this will be taken care by mongoose by default so.. What you want to do is change your query like this

```
Model.find({createdAt:{$gte:params.frm, $lte:params.to}},callback);
```

or if you want to just give a single date try like this

```
Model.find({createdAt:dateTarget},callback);
```

Comment: also note that your target date formate is ok to be used by mongoose to make the conversion implicitly