# Spring Data Mongo: criteria doesn't filter by Date

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I need to filter my data from mongo db collection by date.
I created following query for complete this task:

```
new Criteria(Constants.MONGO_POST_CREATION_DATE).gte(DateUtil.getUTCDate(searchDTO.getStartDate())
```

this criteria generates following query:

```
{ "creationTime" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2018-10-28T21:00:00.000Z"} , "$lte" : { "$date" : "2019-02-06T08:29:00.000Z"}}}
```

But i couldn't get any data by using this query. It just returns empty result list. I've found following question on stackoverflow which explains how to write correct query for filtering by Date:
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819870/date-query-with-isodate-in-mongodb-doesnt-seem-to-work)

So, with query from that answer i'm able to get expected result from mongo:

```
{ "creationTime" : { "$gte" : new Date("2019-01-24T21:00:00.000Z") , "$lte" : new Date("2019-02-06T08:29:00.000Z")}}
```

What do i need to change to force **Criteria** generate proper query for Date?

Comment: I guess the field of your model with the name "Constants.MONGO_POST_CREATION_DATE" is a String and not a Date?

Comment: @James, no, the type of the field is Date

Comment: maybe it does not like that dateutil method? for me using java.time.Instant works almost all times perfectly...