# Troubles with mongodb filtering by query range

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, range

I am having an issue with mongodb. Could anyone explain me why this works (gives back some results):

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"reportedOn" : { "$gte" :    ISODate("2019-03-01T01:20:00"), "$lt" : ISODate("2019-04-01T02:00:00") } });
```

And this doesn't work (returns zero):

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"reportedOn" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : 1551398400000 }, "$lt" : { "$date" : 1554073200000 } } });
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to check this kind of [related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819870/date-query-with-isodate-in-mongodb-doesnt-seem-to-work/19820260) to understand why you actually can't use an epoch time directly in your query.

Here is the interesting part of querying on Date :

According to [Data Types in the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/) both should be equivalent:

> The mongo db provides various methods to return the date, either as a string or as a Date object:
>
> - Date() method which returns the current date as a string.
> - new Date() constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper.
> - ISODate() constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper.

and using `ISODate` [should still return a Date object](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Date/#return-date-as-date-object).

`{"$date": "ISO-8601 string"}` can be used when strict JSON representation is required.

So you may want to check [all ISO-8601 available formats](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169814.htm) and update your code accordingly to the expected format in order to get this working as expected.

Comment: But the proble is that im using java, this way:

Comment: This is independent from the language. You are using the mongodb query language and it's the same for all programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
{ "$date" : { "$numberLong" : "<dateAsMilliseconds>" } }
```

as mentioned in the MongoDB docs instead of comparing with $date only. [Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date)