# Query MongoDB between two dates groovy

Tags: mongodb, date, grails, groovy

I'm trying to get all documents between two dates using groovy. I've tried several approaches and haven't been successful. Most lately I've tried the approach listed here [Java/MongoDB query by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840540/java-mongodb-query-by-date)

Here is my code :

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("lastDate", //
    new BasicDBObject("$gte",start).append("$lt", end));
    def temp=  getDB().sysLog.find(query)
```

However I get the error :

```
     No such property: gte for class: dev.ReportController Possible solutions: DB
```

I can't figure out why this approach will not work. It looks as if groovy handles the "$gte" differently then Java which makes sense but I'm not sure how I should format the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use single quotes

```
new BasicDBObject( '$gte', start ).append( '$lt', end ) )
```

Using double quotes, Groovy tries to expand the `gte` into a Groovy String, but as it says, you have no variable called `gte`

Indeed, you should be able to convert you code to the more groovy:

```
def temp = getDB().sysLog.find( [ lastDate:[ '$gte': start, '$lt': end ] ] as BasicDBObject )
```

Comment: Thank you..can't believe I missed that..DOes the date have to be a certain format/type? At the moment I'm using epoch time but am not getting anything back freom the db even though "start" and "end" have multiple dates between them?

Comment: I think it can just be a `java.util.Date` object