# Find mongodb objects using ISODate using JAVA

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java-driver

The [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb) is answering the mongoshell command. But I require it to do in Java. I have explained my question a bit more. hope this helps

Below is the object

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8f997fcdc2960adae4f91a"),
    "cobDate" : ISODate("2018-02-15T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "Version" : 1
}
```

Query that worked in MongoShell

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({"cobDate" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2018-04-04T00:00:00.000Z"), "$lte" : ISODate("2018-04-06T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

Below is my Java code.

```
        String businessDate = "2018-04-05"; //This is the argument to be passed in string by user
        LocalDate sDate = LocalDate.parse(businessDate);
        LocalDate eDate = sDate.plusDays(1);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date ssdate = format.parse(sDate.toString());
        Date eedate = format.parse(eDate.toString());

        String startDate = MongoConnect.toISO8601UTC(ssdate);
        String endDate = MongoConnect.toISO8601UTC(eedate);

        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("cobDate", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gt", endDate).add("$lte", endDate).get()) ; 

        db.getCollection(collectionName).find(query)
```

here syso(query) output is-->

```
{"cobDate" : { "$gt" : "2018-04-04T00:00:00.000Z", "$lte" : "2018-04-06T00:00:00.000Z" } }
```

and does not work for me where "cobDate" stored like **ISODate("2018-04-05T00:00:00.000Z"**

Comment: MongoDB BSON Dates "are **not** strings". In order to find a "single date" you actually look for the :"range" of possible dates between the start of the day you want and the start of the next day.

Comment: people are not reading question carefully. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840540/java-mongodb-query-by-date will work if date is stored as string like "2018-04-04T00:00:00.000Z" or "Wed Jul 27 16:54:49 EST 2011", but teh answer of this doesnot work for dates stored as ISODate("2018-04-05T00:00:00.000Z"

Answer (score 0):

It's easier and faster to look for dates greater than or equal to your date and less than your date + 1 day than to try parsing text with a regex.

```
String sourceDate = "2018-02-15";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date startDate = format.parse(sourceDate);
Date endDate = DateUtil.addDays(myDate, 1);

collection.find(and(gte("Date", startDate ), lt("Date", endDate )));
```